# Proof of Invariance of Domain in Introduction to Algebraic Topology by Rotman

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

[image]

The following proof above is given in *Introduction to Algebraic Topology by Rotman* and I understand it except for the part where it's claimed that $y \in h(N) \setminus h(\dot{N})$. Now I understand that we must have $y \in h(N)$ since $h(x) = y$ and $x \in N$, but I don't see why $y \not\in h(\dot{N})$.

Why is it the case that $y \not\in h(\dot{N})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in N$, $x\notin\dot N$. As $h$ is a homeomorphism, it is bijective, so
$h(x)\in h(N)$ and $h(x)\notin h(\dot N)$.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, it's not assumed that $x \not\in \dot{N}$ though.

Comment: $\dot N$ is the boundary of $N$, so if $x\in\dot N$, then $N$ is not a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Ohh my bad, $N$ being a closed neighborhood of $x$ implies that $x \in \operatorname{Int}(N)$, I was mixing up the definition of a closed neighborhood